# HTML / CSS two layered layout separately scrollable

Tags: html, css, layout

[image]

Hi team,

I am looking to build such a layout, but I struggle with finding be correct way to do it. I have played around with two divs with position = absolute, but it does not work with all my requirements. Any suggestion on how to get the top-nav in as well as a fixed sub-nav on the right panel?

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#leftCol {
  background: #ddd;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 80%;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#rightCol {
  background: #bbb;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  padding: 2em;
  font-size: 66px;
}
```

```html
<body style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">

  <div>test</div>

  <div id="leftCol">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eu ligula turpis, in euismod velit. Sed suscipit commodo nisl ac tempor. Donec eu nulla eros. Donec tortor justo, eleifend eu consectetur at, fermentum a semidunt rhoncus auctor.</p>

  </div>
  <div id="rightCol">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eu ligula turpis, in euismod velit. Sed suscipit commodo nisl ac tempor. Donec eu nulla eros. Donec tortor justo, eleifend eu consectetur at, fermentum a sem. Vestibulum tempus velit
      vel neque rutrum congue. Donec vehicula dictum mi, sit amet suscipit augue rhoncus vitae. Curabitur tempus auctor bibendum. Sed sodales iaculis egestas. Suspendisse consectetur elementum ligula et imperdiet. Proin in velit eu arcu dapibus faucibus.
      Vivamus fringilla adipiscing mauris ac condimentum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse ut nibh ac nulla tempus malesuada. Ut congue, arcu quis semper pellentesque, nunc quam
      volutpat libero, a rhoncus metus sem eu dolor. Vestibulum lacinia augue sit amet nibh imperdiet eu volutpat nibh egestas. Suspendisse luctus laoreet mattis. Proin in euismod augue. Duis tincidunt rhoncus auctor.</p>


  </div>

</body>
```

Thank you!
fj

Comment: Tip: don't use position absolute, you can obatin this layout just using flexbox or grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a fan of `grid-template-areas` for this. See below:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "nav nav"
    "sidebar subnav"
    "sidebar main"
    ;
  grid-template-rows: fit-content(2rem) fit-content(2rem) 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 10rem 1fr;
}

nav {
  background-color: #4472C4;
  grid-area: nav;
  display: flex;
}

nav .spacer {
  flex-grow:2;
}

.nav-item, .subnav-item {
  padding: 0.5rem 0.25rem;
}

aside {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ED7D31;
  grid-area: sidebar;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.aside-scrollable {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  overflow-y:auto;
  
}

.subnav {
  background-color: #00B050;
  grid-area: subnav; 
  display: flex;
}

main {
  background-color: #A9D18E;
  grid-area: main; 
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class='nav-item'>Left-side icon (fixed)</div>
  <div class='spacer'></div>
  <div class='nav-item'>Item 1</div>
  <div class='nav-item'>Item 2</div>
<div class='nav-item'>Item 3</div>
</nav>
<aside>
  <div class='aside-scrollable'>
    Left side scrollable
  </div>
    </aside>
<div class='subnav'>
  <div class='subnav-item'>Item 1</div>
  <div class='subnav-item'>Item 2</div>
  <div class='subnav-item'>Item 3</div>
  <div class='subnav-item'>Item 4</div>
  <div class='subnav-item'>Item 5</div>
</div>
<main>
  Some content here
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - this was super quick and the way to do it with grid is amazing!!

Comment: Hi Adam, what are the pros and cons with flex or grid (see below)?

Comment: Flexbox has more flexibility, and is good if you've got a single line or columns to style. As you can see from my example I've used flex for the navbars. Grid is a bit more structured and is pretty daunting at first but is really powerful. Have a look at [this video](https://youtu.be/3elGSZSWTbM) too

Answer (score 0):

I would use flex for your main layout and then absolutely positioned elements for your scroll areas:

**Basic Layout**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: blue;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  width: 200px;
  background: orange;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-header {
  background: green;
}
.content-body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.scroll-container {
  position: relative;
}

.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <nav class="scroll-container">
    <div class="scroll">nav</div>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-header">content header</div>
    <div class="content-body scroll-container">
      <div class="scroll">content body</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

**With enough content to scroll**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: blue;
}

main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

nav {
  width: 200px;
  background: orange;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content-header {
  background: green;
}

.content-body {
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}

.scroll-container {
  position: relative;
}

.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* this is just to create height so it makes the container overflow */
.scroll-block {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <nav class="scroll-container">
    <div class="scroll">
      nav
      <div class="scroll-block"></div>
      nav bottom
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-header">content header</div>
    <div class="content-body scroll-container">
      <div class="scroll">
        content body
        <div class="scroll-block"></div>
        content body bottom
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: This is really good as well! What are the pros and cons in comparison to the grid-way (above) to doing it with flex and absolute?

Comment: I guess flex needs a few more elements.  not sure if this is still the case but safari may have issues with `grid-template-rows` - see known issues: https://caniuse.com/?search=css%20grid

Answer (score -1):

You'd need a fixed height on the scrollable items and you need your vertical overflow set to scroll.

That's how I did it anyway:

```
.createForm form {
    height: 80vh !important;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: are you sure using !important is a good idea?

Comment: Thanks Logan - the above flex / grid ways of doing it might be more robust?

Comment: @user1827421 are you asking me or telling me? I'm not here to force you to use a particular solution; do what works best for you.

Comment: @Sfili_81 I'm sure this works in my app. I can't see any reason why it would be a bad idea particularly because I'm specifically targeting a particular element. Why don't you tell me why it wouldn't be a good idea?

Comment: For [example](https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/)